# is_page home is not working at WP script enqueing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add a specific script to `front-page.php` by filtering through `if(is_page('home') ) {}` like

```
if(is_page('home') ) {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'slider', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/slider.min.js', array('jquery'),'',true );
}
```

but this is not working! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a function [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) you can use to check this.

> It returns TRUE when the main blog page is being displayed and the Settings->Reading->Front page displays is set to "Your latest posts", or when is set to "A static page" and the "Front Page" value is the current Page being displayed.

```
if( is_front_page() ) {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slider.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jordi, but how about our custom pages? like for example `product` page , what if I want to add a an specific script thete?

Comment: Then you could use `is_page($param)` but make sure `$param` is a valid _Page ID, title, slug, or array of such._